# How to implement "Change of mind" ability into the bot or conversation for any given intent in Dialogflow?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Consider a scenario where user wants to order a meal :

User : I would like to order 1 burger 1 orange juice and one coffee

Bot : Would you like to have a veg burger or a non-veg one?

User: A veg burger

User: **Sorry**, I would like it to be **non-veg**

Bot: (Generally how would we handle this change of mind without having to start the conversation from scratch) ?

In this part where I've been implementing something like a bus ticket booking, this the bot seems to remember the previous order that is veg-burger or some how ends up falling on to default intent or fallback intent whichever is suitable. But I would like to know if there is a way for letting the bot know that the user has "Changed the mind" (Hopefully it is possible using or manipulating the context) and wants a non-veg burger now?

Can we work out an followup intent recognizing words like Sorry and then entity such as type i.e. non-veg here. What is the best practice? Because starting the conversation from scratch doesn't seem to be a good idea from UX point of view.

Comment: you can use context to handle this situation and also add a confirmation flow before submitting the request to the server

Comment: Yes that is what I need to know, how can we manipulate the context and use it to change value of entity. There is a prompt before sending server request, but I don't understand how can context be used to handle this situation.

Comment: Context is used for managing conversation state or linking conversation. In your case when user says "I would like to order 1 burger 1 orange juice and one coffee" then set a output context as "orderstart" and then create intent that has  got input context  configured as "orderstart" .

Comment: Also you can piggy back data in context if you want to do some manipulation

Comment: By piggyback do you mean, while being in same conversation I can change the order right like veg-burger to non-veg burger? That is what I mean to ask how to do it, I couldn't understand it from documentation.

Comment: Yes if you are setting a context that you can set parameter which is a key value pair to pass data back and forth during conversation

Comment: Yes the same parameter I am talking about, how can we change it's value suddenly, suppose we also ordered a pizza which was veg now, how to inform DF which parameter to change, when user says I want it to be non-veg, because the parameters would be pizza-type:non-veg and burger-type:non-veg but both point to same entity that is food

Answer (score 1):

Good day TGW,

You have 2 options, either you split your intents into a search intent and book intent e.g. search.salad and buy.salad intents OR you have a confirmation step before you actually send to Fulfilment.

If you choose to split your intents into 2 then a similar flow should work for you:

1. If the food type is finite then create an entity with the options.
2. Add your search.salad intent that should have most of what the users will say to order a salad. Remember to incoporate the entity from step 1.
3. Add a followup intent to your search.salad Intent, and select **custom** from the options.
4. In this newly created followup Intent add the **User says** that you want to use to update the search, enable fulfilment and save.

**NB:** Ensure the newly created intent has an intent that ends with *-followup in the In-context and this same intent is in the Out-context of the search.salad intent. Dialogflow will automatically update the parameters for you based on what the user enters.

The second option is similar to this, you can add your confirmation step as a followup to the search.salad intent and enable fulfilment only on the confirmation intent.

Comment: The only thing is I need to create a followup intent that checks for user's change for every intent, it becomes difficult to manage so many followup intents